# Code crashes on calling delete

Tags: c++, crash

This may be a stupid question, but why does this code crash when calling delete? From reading other questions I know this probably results in undefined behavior but I don't see exactly why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* resize (char* result, int& size){
  char * temp;
  temp = new char [size*10];
  for (int i=0;i<size;i++) temp[i]=result[i];
  size*=10;
  //delete[] result;
  return temp;
}

void transform(char in[], const char p1[], const char p2[]){
  int resultlength=100, inputindex=0, outputindex=0;
  char* result = new char[resultlength];

  while (in[inputindex]){
    result[outputindex++]=in[inputindex++];

    if (inputindex>=resultlength) result = resize (result,resultlength);
  }
  in[outputindex--]=0;
  while(outputindex>=0) in[outputindex]=result[outputindex--];
  //delete[] result;
}


int main(){
  char  t[200]="123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345";
  transform(t,"hfgh","dfsdfds");
  int i=0;
  while(t[i]) cout<<t[i++];
  cout<<endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `result = temp` means nothing to the caller of your function. Pass that pointer by reference, or perhaps utilize the otherwise unused return value of your function. This question has *hundreds* of duplicates, but the titles, descriptions, and content are so divergent it can be challenging to pin one down.

Comment: I've changed so it passes a reference to a pointer and it still crashes upon reaching delete.

Comment: I feel so stupid now but yes, the typo was a problem (besides the other mistake). Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

@WhozCraig's comment is right on the money. The crux of the problem is that

```
delete[] result;
```

makes the pointer in the calling function a dangling pointer.

The line

```
result=temp;
```

does nothing to the pointer in the calling function. The calling function still has a dangling pointer.

**Solution 1**

Change the argument to be a reference to a pointer.

```
void resize (char*& result, int& size){
 ...
}
```

**Solution 2**

Return the newly allocated memory as the return value.

```
char* resize (char* result, int& size){
   char * temp;
   temp = new char (size*10);
   for (int i=0;i<size;i++) temp[i]=result[i];
   size*=10;
   delete[] result;
   return temp;
}
```

and make sure to use

```
result = resize(result, resultlength);
```

in the calling function.

**Solution 3**

Instead of using `char* result`, use `std::string result` or `std::vector<char> result`.

**Update, after seeing the MCVE**

The line

```
while(outputindex>=0) in[outputindex]=result[outputindex--];
```

causes undefined behavior. By using `gcc -Wall`, I get the following diagnostic:

```
socc.cc: In function ‘void transform(char*, const char*, const char*)’:
socc.cc:22:62: warning: operation on ‘outputindex’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
   while(outputindex>=0) in[outputindex]=result[outputindex--];

                                                          ^
```

After changing that to:

```
while(outputindex>=0)
{
   in[outputindex]=result[outputindex];
   --outputindex;
}
```

the program ran fine for me.

Comment: Use `std::vector` FFS.

Comment: I was expecting something like this and you're right, but isn't there one more mistake in my code? because I've tried both solutions and the code still crashes at delete...

Comment: @user3019593, you need to post a [mcve] so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: I've editted my post to add main. Basically that's my whole code at this moment.

Comment: Ok, as Avi Berger pointed out, there was a typo. You missed it too :) case closed, thank you very, very much.

Comment: @user3019593, see the Update.

Answer (score 0):

1. result could be null, be sure to check at the top of the function
2. What you are doing is deleting result in resize. But since the pointer isn't passed by reference the result pointer outside of the resize function is pointing to deleted memory. So either pass the pointer by reference or change it to

> ```
> resize(char ** result,....){
>    //Resize stuff
>    delete result*;//Deleting the stuff pointed to by result
>    result* = temp;// Assigning the pointer outside the function to temp
> }
> ```

Then you would call resize like

```
resize(&result,resultlength)
```

EDIT:
To change the resize to get the pointer by reference change the declaration to

```
resize(char*& result,...)
```

and thats it, much simpler that the pointer to pointer method.

Comment: In C++, passing a reference to the pointer is the preferred idiom.